# Is there a way to get influxdb (0.12) to not merge series?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have a measurement with a tag of host.  For grafana, I would like to return several series to grafana so I can plot a line for each host. If I do mean(value), influxdb merges all of host's series into one.

I used to have several measurements, one for each host, and it worked with a wildcard.  I would like the option of not merging the series or merging it.  How do I express this?

I can do a group by host, but I can't seem to include host in the select list.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean by `I can't seem to include host in the select list.`. Grafana does provide [templating](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/) that will let you select an individual host  that may achieve a similar result to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of doing `group by` InfluxDB will alway merge the data for each series queried.